# Using Smpp in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms, smpp

The need to send and receive SMS messages via Smpp, Register Number, received systemID and password, but fails to connect. Connected to the project gem 'ruby-smpp', to use the example of the getaway [this](https://github.com/raykrueger/ruby-smpp/blob/master/examples/sample_gateway.rb), it only changed the values ​​systemID and password.

in the logs:

```
<- (BindTransceiver) len = 37 cmd = 9 status = 0 seq = 1364360797 (<systemID><password>)
Hex dump follows:
<- 00000000: 0000 0025 0000 0009 0000 0000 5152 7e5d | ...% ........ QR ~]
<- 00000010: 3531 3639 3030 0068 4649 6b4b 7d7d 7a00 | <systemID>.<password>.
<- 00000020: 0034 0001 00 | .4 ...

Starting enquire link timer (with 10s interval)
Delegate: transceiver unbound
```

in the console:

```
Connecting to SMSC ...
MT: Disconnected. Reconnecting in 5 seconds ..
MT: Disconnected. Reconnecting in 5 seconds ..
MT: Disconnected. Reconnecting in 5 seconds ..
MT: Disconnected. Reconnecting in 5 seconds ..
MT: Disconnected. Reconnecting in 5 seconds ..
```

Tell me, please, I do not, maybe in the config to something else to add or change? And smpp connection, as I understand, it works only with a specific IP-address, but the logs on the server and on the local machine are the same

```
class Gateway
  include KeyboardHandler

  # MT id counter. 
  @@mt_id = 0

  # expose SMPP transceiver's send_mt method
  def self.send_mt(*args)
    @@mt_id += 1
    @@tx.send_mt(@@mt_id, *args)
  end

  def logger
    Smpp::Base.logger
  end

  def start(config)
    # The transceiver sends MT messages to the SMSC. It needs a storage with Hash-like
    # semantics to map SMSC message IDs to your own message IDs.
    pdr_storage = {} 

    # Run EventMachine in loop so we can reconnect when the SMSC drops our connection.
    puts "Connecting to SMSC..."
    loop do
      EventMachine::run do
        @@tx = EventMachine::connect(
          config[:host], 
          config[:port], 
          Smpp::Transceiver, 
          config, 
          self    # delegate that will receive callbacks on MOs and DRs and other events
        )
        print "MT: "
        $stdout.flush

        # Start consuming MT messages (in this case, from the console)
        # Normally, you'd hook this up to a message queue such as Starling
        # or ActiveMQ via STOMP.
        EventMachine::open_keyboard(KeyboardHandler)
      end
      puts "Disconnected. Reconnecting in 5 seconds.."
      sleep 5
    end
  end

  # ruby-smpp delegate methods 

  def mo_received(transceiver, pdu)
    logger.info "Delegate: mo_received: from #{pdu.source_addr} to #{pdu.destination_addr}: #{pdu.short_message}"
  end

  def delivery_report_received(transceiver, pdu)
    logger.info "Delegate: delivery_report_received: ref #{pdu.msg_reference} stat #{pdu.stat}"
  end

  def message_accepted(transceiver, mt_message_id, pdu)
    logger.info "Delegate: message_accepted: id #{mt_message_id} smsc ref id: #{pdu.message_id}"
  end

  def message_rejected(transceiver, mt_message_id, pdu)
    logger.info "Delegate: message_rejected: id #{mt_message_id} smsc ref id: #{pdu.message_id}"
  end

  def bound(transceiver)
    logger.info "Delegate: transceiver bound"
  end

  def unbound(transceiver)  
    logger.info "Delegate: transceiver unbound"
    EventMachine::stop_event_loop
  end

end


module KeyboardHandler
  include EventMachine::Protocols::LineText2

  def receive_line(data)
    sender, receiver, *body_parts = data.split
    unless sender && receiver && body_parts.size > 0
      puts "Syntax: <sender> <receiver> <message body>"      
    else
      body = body_parts.join(' ')
      puts "Sending MT from #{sender} to #{receiver}: #{body}"  
      SampleGateway.send_mt(sender, receiver, body)
    end
    prompt
  end

  def prompt
    print "MT: "
    $stdout.flush
  end
end
```

/initializers

```
require 'eventmachine'
require 'smpp'

LOGFILE = Rails.root + "log/sms_gateway.log"
Smpp::Base.logger = Logger.new(LOGFILE)
```

/script

```
puts "Starting SMS Gateway. Please check the log at #{LOGFILE}"
config = {
  :host => '127.0.0.1',
  :port => 6000,
  :system_id => <SystemID>,
  :password => <Password>,
  :system_type => '', # default given according to SMPP 3.4 Spec
  :interface_version => 52,
  :source_ton  => 0,
  :source_npi => 1,
  :destination_ton => 1,
  :destination_npi => 1,
  :source_address_range => '',
  :destination_address_range => '',
  :enquire_link_delay_secs => 10
}
gw = Gateway.new
gw.start(config)
```

file from the script / run through the rails runner

Comment: check host and port settings. is smsc located on same machine as rails app?

Comment: no, my mistake, smsc provide individual service, how to get the host and port, try again

Comment: Entered the correct ip-address and port, but there was a problem sending Russian characters, added
`# coding: utf-8`
in the script / and gateway.rb, but it did not help

Comment: I'm not sure if this library converts messages itself. I suggest trying to convert your messages from UTF-8 to UCS-2BE before sending.

Comment: not all characters are converting
`Iconv.iconv("UTF-8","UCS-2BE",line)
Iconv::InvalidCharacter: ")"`

Comment: and I do not know where to perform encoding

Comment: message comes send_mt encoding ASCII-8BIT, when trying to transcode to UCS-2BE error

send_mt: incompatible character encodings: US-ASCII and UTF-16BE (Encoding :: CompatibilityError)

`# expose SMPP transceiver's send_mt method
  def self.send_mt(*args)
    @@mt_id += 1
    puts args[2].encoding
    args[2] = args[2].force_encoding("UCS-2BE")
    puts args[2].encoding
    @@tx.send_mt(@@mt_id, *args)
  end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Initially were incorrectly specified host and port, as smpp-server was not on the same machine as the RoR-application. As for encoding, sending in Russian layout should be

```
message = text.encode ("UTF-16BE"). force_encoding ("BINARY")
Gateway.send_mt (sender, receiver, message, data_coding: 8)
```

To receive a form in the right

```
message = pdu.short_message.force_encoding ('UTF-16BE'). encode ('UTF-8')
```

Comment: hi, i'm using ruby-smpp with ussd, getting unreadable symbols when submitting short message encoded to UCS2